# How to convert from string to a number, and vice-versa in C++?

Tags: c++, string

DEAR All

I'm new to the C++, so  maybe someone can say what the proper way to write a function that gets a string char (represents number) and converts it to the integer number.

For example : input : Sixty five, output: 65.

Maybe it should use by cin.getline() ?

Well, vice-versa is little bit simlper...

Thanks for advance.
Igal

Comment: Is this homework? Why else would you want to do that?

Comment: `cin.getline()` is a good start; then you'll need a natural language parser, which isn't so straightforward. You'll have a much easier time if you take input like "65". Joel Hoff's answer shows how to convert that.

Comment: @Mike - I adjusted my answer to illustrate an NLP parser approach after reading the problem more closely.

Comment: I went and added a `homework` tag. feel free to remove it if my suspicion was wrong. Note that homework questions are fine on SO. The general consensus is just that they should be answered in a way to maximize their teaching effect. (Whereas other questions should be answered so that whoever asks gets to go on with their work as quickly as possible.)

Comment: Dear All, Thanks for your comments, I'm appreciate this.  Well, strictly speaking, this is not for homework (I passed Introductory course for C++), I'm just wish to improve my computing skills, as I'm feel it need some (a lot ;-) improvement. I'm using Deitel's "C++ how to Program" for my self-learning.      Thanks again.

Comment: @Igal: Fine, so I went and removed the `homework` tag. (Although, while strictl speaking this might not be homework, you might gain more from a homework-like answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an illustration of a key part of a solution:

```
const char* digits[] = {"zero", "one", "two", ...};
const char* tens[] = {"ten", "twenty", "thirty", ...};

// Loop to compare input text tokens against above
...
```

The idea is to simplify conversion from text to digits by using the array index for the corresponding text token as the means for converting to the digit, adjusting for any array index start differences.

Use either the `strcmp` C function or the `==` C++ string comparison operator depending on what datatypes you have for the input text tokens.

Comment: @Peter - Thanks, it's a little early in the day here still. ;-)

Comment: we all just humans, even if we deals with computers... :-).  Your answer is very ineresting.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to do it in Ruby (handles fractions as well):

http://github.com/jduff/numerizer/blob/master/lib/numerizer.rb

It shouldn't be too hard to translate to C++